# How to combine all strings from mutiple txt files and sort them in one array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parsing

I have three txt files that I'm trying to combine and once they all parsed, I have to sort them all into three different outputs. So far I have been able to parse all files and used three different foreach statements for them. For each line from the files, I have to label them with different attributes for each string. My goal is to get them all into one array and sort them. Here is my code so far:

space.txt

```
last_name first_name middle_initial gender dob fav_color
Kournikova Anna F F 6-3-1975 Red
Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green
Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black
```

comma.txt

```
last_name, first_name, gender, dob, fav_color
Abercrombie, Neil, Male, Tan, 2/13/1943
Bishop, Timothy, Male, Yellow, 4/23/1967
Kelly, Sue, Female, Pink, 7/12/1959
```

pipe.txt

```
last_name | first_name  | middle_initial | gender | dob | fav_color
Smith | Steve | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Bonk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1975
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
```

data.php

```
<?php 

    $space_txt = './data/input/space.txt';
    $comma_txt = './data/input/comma.txt';
    $pipe_txt = './data/input/pipe.txt';

    $parsed_space_data = file_get_contents($space_txt);
    $parsed_comma_data = file_get_contents($comma_txt);
    $parsed_pipe_data = file_get_contents($pipe_txt);

    $spaces = explode("\r", $parsed_space_data);
    $commas = explode("\r", $parsed_comma_data);
    $pipes = explode("\r", $parsed_pipe_data);




    foreach ($spaces as $space => $data) {
        $space_data = explode(' ' , $data);

        $info[$space]['last_name'] = $space_data[0];
        $info[$space]["first_name"] = $space_data[1];
        $info[$space]["middle_initial"] = $space_data[2];
        $info[$space]["gender"] = $space_data[3];
        $info[$space]["date_of_birth"] = $space_data[4];
        $info[$space]["favorite_color"] = $space_data[5];


        $s_array = implode(' ' , array($info[$space]['last_name'], $info[$space]["first_name"], $info[$space]["gender"], $info[$space]["date_of_birth"], $info[$space]["favorite_color"]));


        $space_old_data = array("F", "-");
        $space_new_data = array("Female", "/");

        $space_array = str_replace($space_old_data, $space_new_data, $s_array);





        echo $space_array . '<br><br>';


    }

    foreach ($commas as $comma => $data) {
        $comma_data = explode(',', $data);

        $info[$comma]["last_name"] = $comma_data[0];
        $info[$comma]["first_name"] = $comma_data[1];
        $info[$comma]["gender"] = $comma_data[2];
        $info[$comma]["favorite_color"] = $comma_data[3];
        $info[$comma]["date_of_birth"] = $comma_data[4];

        $comma_array = implode(' ' , array($info[$comma]['last_name'], $info[$comma]["first_name"],  $info[$pipe]["middle_initial"],$info[$comma]["gender"], $info[$comma]["date_of_birth"], $info[$comma]["favorite_color"]));


         echo $comma_array  . '<br><br>';


    }

    foreach ($pipes as $pipe => $data) {
        $pipe_data = explode(' |', $data);

        $info[$pipe]["last_name"] = $pipe_data[0];
        $info[$pipe]["first_name"] = $pipe_data[1];
        $info[$pipe]["middle_initial"] = $pipe_data[2];
        $info[$pipe]["gender"] = $pipe_data[3];
        $info[$pipe]["favorite_color"] = $pipe_data[4];
        $info[$pipe]["date_of_birth"] = $pipe_data[5];




        $p_array = implode(' ' , array($info[$pipe]['last_name'], $info[$pipe]["first_name"], $info[$pipe]["middle_initial"], $info[$pipe]["gender"], $info[$pipe]["favorite_color"], $info[$pipe]["date_of_birth"]));


        $pipe_old_data = array("M", "-");
        $pipe_new_data = array("Male", "/");

        $pipe_array = str_replace($pipe_old_data, $pipe_new_data, $p_array);





        echo $pipe_array . '<br><br>';





}









 ?>
```

The following outputs should be:

Output 1

```
Hingis Martina Female 4/2/1979 Green
Kelly Sue Female 7/12/1959 Pink
Kournikova Anna Female 6/3/1975 Red
Seles Monica Female 12/2/1973 Black
Abercrombie Neil Male 2/13/1943 Tan
Bishop Timothy Male 4/23/1967 Yellow
Bonk Radek Male 6/3/1975 Green
Bouillon Francis Male 6/3/1975 Blue
Smith Steve Male 3/3/1985 Red
```

Output 2

```
Abercrombie Neil Male 2/13/1943 Tan
Kelly Sue Female 7/12/1959 Pink
Bishop Timothy Male 4/23/1967 Yellow
Seles Monica Female 12/2/1973 Black
Bonk Radek Male 6/3/1975 Green
Bouillon Francis Male 6/3/1975 Blue
Kournikova Anna Female 6/3/1975 Red
Hingis Martina Female 4/2/1979 Green
Smith Steve Male 3/3/1985 Red
```

Output3

```
Smith Steve Male 3/3/1985 Red
Seles Monica Female 12/2/1973 Black
Kournikova Anna Female 6/3/1975 Red
Kelly Sue Female 7/12/1959 Pink
Hingis Martina Female 4/2/1979 Green
Bouillon Francis Male 6/3/1975 Blue
Bonk Radek Male 6/3/1975 Green
Bishop Timothy Male 4/23/1967 Yellow
Abercrombie Neil Male 2/13/1943 Tan
```

Outside of each foreach statements, when I print an array, it only prints the last line from each file. What can I do to simplify the code in order to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Here $comma_array = implode() it should be like this $comma_array[]

Comment: Just to clear up your terminology, you're using `implode`, which converts an array to string. Therefore you are outputting a string within the foreach. If you want to make one big string, you can concatenate each line using the `.=` operator. E.g. `$pipe_output .= $pipe_array . '<br><br>';` Then `$pipe_output` would be available with all lines outside the loop

Comment: But each string has to be set to a specific attribute

Comment: In which case you're better off putting each line into an array using the double square bracket method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put it all in one loop, but you could also make a function for it instead of using multiple `if`s

```
//$space_txt = './data/input/space.txt';
//$comma_txt = './data/input/comma.txt';
//$pipe_txt = './data/input/pipe.txt';

//$parsed_space_data = file_get_contents($space_txt);
//$parsed_comma_data = file_get_contents($comma_txt);
//$parsed_pipe_data = file_get_contents($pipe_txt);


$spaceArray  = myExpldeLoopFunc("space"," ",$parsed_space_data);
$commaArray  = myExpldeLoopFunc("comma",",",$parsed_comma_data);
$pipeArray   = myExpldeLoopFunc("pipe","|",$parsed_pipe_data);

$finalArray = array_merge($spaceArray,$commaArray,$pipeArray);


function myExpldeLoopFunc($name, $sep, $data){

   $parsedData = explode("\r", $data);

   $arr = [];
   foreach($parsedData as $data):
      $dataArr = explode($sep, $data);

      if($name == 'space'):
           $arr[] = [
            "last_name"      => $dataArr[0],
            "first_name"     => $dataArr[1],
            "middle_initial" => $dataArr[2],
            "gender"         => $dataArr[3],
            "date_of_birth"  => $dataArr[4],
            "favorite_color" => $dataArr[5]
          ];
      elseif($name == 'comma'):
          $arr[] = [
            "last_name"      => $dataArr[0],
            "first_name"     => $dataArr[1],
            "gender"         => $dataArr[2],
            "favorite_color" => $dataArr[3],
            "date_of_birth"  => $dataArr[4]
          ];
      else:
          $arr[] = [
            "last_name"      => $dataArr[0],
            "first_name"     => $dataArr[1],
            "middle_initial" => $dataArr[2],
            "gender"         => $dataArr[3],
            "favorite_color" => $dataArr[4],
            "date_of_birth"  => $dataArr[5]
        ];
    endif;

   endforeach;

   return $arr;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a great solution, but I have to be able to parse my files and output data according to the syntax you gave me.

Comment: Added a function for exploding each text.

Comment: I get a undefined offset 5 error on "date_of_birth"  => $dataArr[5] in 'pipes' and when i did elseif ($name = 'pipes){}, nothing shows even when I've echoed $arr;

Comment: Also I did var_dump($finalArray); and it only prints the last line from each file

Comment: Can you check each files `$parsed_space_data = file_get_contents($space_txt); $parsedData = explode("\r",$parsed_space_data); ` To see if you get an array from line breaks?

Comment: Just found out $space_array and $comma_array are empty using var_dump but $parsed_space_data and $parsed_comma_data still have data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115413/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-ervald).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a miltidimensional array of the arrays. Instead of

```
$space_array = str_replace($space_old_data, $space_new_data, $s_array);
```

use

```
$space_array[] = str_replace($space_old_data, $space_new_data, $s_array);
```

And then outside of the foreach use `print_r` to dump all the data

```
print_r($space_array)
```

Comment: That gave me the "Array to string conversion" error

Comment: You'll need to remove/comment out where you are currently echoing inside the foreaches

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) in your case

Something like this

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$handle = fopen('/path/to/file','r');
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) !== FALSE ) {
//process
}
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);
```

Or if you don't want auto detect . You can specify separator as 3rd argument for fgetcsv